# flex image row shrink without wrappers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How i can make flex 1 row with height 100px; no-wrap; images shrink; without wrappers any img tag; allow use object-fit; imges can be any size;  if image hight less 100px then not stratch by height (see last image)

```
<div class="row">
       <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/1.jpg" >
       <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/2.jpg" >
       <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/3.jpg" >
</div>

.row{
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    display: flex;
}
.row img {
    object-fit: cover;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

desired result:

[image]

if more image

[image]

Comment: Could you edit the description of your question? I am having a hard time figuring out what you're asking for.

Comment: min-wdith:0 to your images